# Javascript to Coffeescript conversion

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Being not the best with javascript I am converting my file to coffeescript.

Here is my original JS

```
function makeTall(){ 
    jQuery(this).find('ul:first').slideDown(
        {queue:false, duration:220}
    );
}
```

I have tried the following.

```
makeTall ->
    jQuery(@).find('ul:first').slideDown
        queue:false
        duration:220
```

Which produces.

```
makeTall(function() {
  return jQuery(this).find('ul:first').slideDown({
    queue: false,
    duration: 220
  });
});
```

The new style just confuses me a little and wanted to ask is this correct ?

I also tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're simply missing the `=` sign before the function literal:

```
makeTall = ->
    jQuery(@).find('ul:first').slideDown
        queue:false
        duration:220
```

Answer (score 3):

You might find this project to be helpful

https://github.com/rstacruz/js2coffee/

For your above case it produces:

```
makeTall = ->
  jQuery(this).find('ul:first').slideDown
    queue: false
    duration: 220
```